# How to duplicate object in react

Tags: reactjs

Even replicating the object succeeded. However, the id value is duplicated the same. Therefore, if you click the delete button, the deletion will be done together.But I want to get a different ID. How can I fix it here?

```
      const handleduplicate = id => {
    
        const dupDataGroup = [...Groupdata].filter(item => item.id === id);
        const newGroup = [dupDataGroup[0], ...Groupdata];
    
        setGroupData(newGroup);
      };
```

The result when I didn't do anything =>

```
0: {id: 0, title: 'blur', subtitle: 'Img'}
1: {id: 1, title: 'blurs', subtitle: 'Ima'}
2: {id: 2, title: 'Free ', subtitle: 'Ima'}
```

handleduplicate click result=>

```
0: {**id: 0**, title: 'blur', subtitle: 'Img'}
1: {**id: 0,** title: 'blur', subtitle: 'Img'}
2: {id: 1, title: 'blurs', subtitle: 'Ima'}
3: {id: 2, title: 'Free ', subtitle: 'Ima'}
```

I hope that only the ID value will change when duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

`[...Groupdata]` creates a new list with the (non-duplicated) items in `Groupdata`. This is important if you'd want to add the item twice to the list, as changing one with change the same object as you already noticed. You will also have to duplicate the item itself.

Note that duplicating the list itself isn't necessary if you're just going to filter on it.

What I also think is happening, given the additional information in the comments, is that `setGroupData` is used multiple times. If you use `Groupdata`, followed by `setGroupData`, then `Groupdata` is not updated accordingly. So just make sure you use that function once.

```
const handleduplicate = (groupData, id, newId) => {
    const dupDataGroup = groupData.filter(item => item.id === id); // no copying here.
    const rest = groupData.filter(item => item.id !== id);

    const newGroup = [
        {  // the item is duplicated (note: no deep copy)
            ...dupDataGroup[0],
            id: newId // updated with the new identifier
        }, 
        ...rest
    ];

    return newGroup;
};

const duplicated = handleduplicate(Groupdata, 123, 456);
setGroupData(duplicated);
```

Comment: The results won't change.

Comment: const handleDelete = id => {
    setGroupData(Groupdata.filter(item => item.id !== id));
    alert('Deleted successfully.');
  };

Comment: If you click Delete, it will still be deleted.

Comment: Could you specify what needs to happen, because I can't quite tell from the comments? I have the feeling you want to duplicate an item, but also want to remove some. Is it that you want to duplicate the item, give it a new ID and then delete the old one?

Comment: What you're saying is correct. I want to duplicate and delete.However, the id is the same, so the duplicated ones are deleted altogether.

Comment: Could you have a peek, and see if this solves the issue?

Comment: Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: Sure, you'll have to execute this only when you want to replace the item, which is only once. You'd not want this to happen every time the screen is rendered. Could you put that code near where you want this to happen, such as onload or a button press?

Answer (score 0):

React does not automatically update the key index in JSON objects. Also, in this scenario, you're fetching the value and inserting it into the `newGroup`.

If you really want to update the keys, I'd suggest creating a for loop to update the values of `id`.

```
const handleduplicate = id => {

    const dupDataGroup = [...Groupdata].filter(item => item.id === id);
    const newGroup = [dupDataGroup[0], ...Groupdata];

    for (var i = 0; i < newGroup.length; i++)
      newGroup[i].id = i;

    setGroupData(newGroup);
  };
```

Comment: There are possibly better ways of doing this, but this works

Comment: Your code and my code result are the same.

Comment: Reproduce the problem in your project in codesandbox and post the link here.

Answer (score 0):

You can duplicate an object by using the spread operator.

```
const obj = {name: 'ritik', surname: 'banger'};
const objCopy = {...obj};
```

or use of Object.assign will work for you.

`let objcopy = Object.assign({}, obj);`

You must note that here we are referencing the original object 'obj' and thus any changes in 'objcopy' will reflect in 'obj', this is known as shallow copy.

If you want to deep copy the object and you wish to have different reference for both then,

Using JQuery library:

```
import jQ from "jquery"; 
let objcopy = jQ.extend(true, obj, {});
```

Using lodash library:

```
var objects = [{ 'a': 1 }, { 'b': 2 }];
var deep = _.cloneDeep(objects);
console.log(deep[0] === objects[0]);
// => false
```